# Regex to find the commented Code in XCode

Tags: ios, regex, xcode, search, comments

I am trying to make a regex that will find all the commented code in Xcode project. Note that result of Regex must only contain commented code and must not contain the comments that we add to make the project more understandable.

Result of regex searching not contain the line like below

```
// this comment is added to make the function understandable
```

But contain the lines like

```
//  [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I successfully make my required expression and it is

```
^.*/[/,\*].*;.*$
```

This will only find your single line or multiline commented code.

Comment: How to use this regex ?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

To anyone wondering how to use regular expression
search **"^.*/[/,*].*;.*$"** after selecting regular expression option from find menu after doing global search(command + shift + F)